# Are there any undesirable side-effects from bootstrapping from an assembly without any services embedded in it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I just installed MVC5 and ServiceStack.Host.Mvc into a empty ASP.NET project. MVC for the Routing, Bundling/Minification and ServiceStack for everything else (IoC, Cache, ect.). This site will only be used to deliver views (SPA Islands I call them) and these rendered views will in turn call another ServiceStack RESTful API site.

So my questions is this "Since I have to bootstrap ServiceStack with the AppHostBase which wants an assembly with a Service in it, is there any harm if I just use the current assembly with-out any services as the snippet below illustrates?"

```
public AppHost()
        : base("Website UI", typeof(MyRootNamespace.Global).Assembly) { }
```

Everything still seems to work in controllers that inherit from ServiceStackController, at least the IoC.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, ServiceStack just uses the list of assemblies specified in the AppHost constructor to scan and autowire any `IService`'s it can find in those assemblies, which in this case there just wont be any.